# In Excel, how do I link to a Sharepoint file instead of the synced local file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, sharepoint

Our office recently migrated all of our files to being stored on Sharepoint, so I'm still getting used to it.

In Excel, I am linking to an external file that is located in a Sharepoint folder that I have synced to my computer. Unfortunately, it seems to link to a locally-saved version of the file, so if someone else opens up the file containing the link, they get #REF errors.

In the excel formula, the linked cell shows up like this: ='C:\Users\My.Name\My Sharepoint\Folder Name[My File.xlsx]Worksheet'!$A$1

Instead, I want it to link to the version of the file that is saved on Sharepoint. That way, anyone who opens up the file would be able to see the linked data and not get #REF errors. How do I do this?

I have already tried changing the source through Edit Links, but this doesn't work. I would prefer to not have to edit links and change the source every single time that I have to link files; ideally, there would be a setting that I can adjust to have it always link to the Sharepoint version of the file instead of the locally saved version.

Comment: [Answer to a similar question to yours](https://superuser.com/a/1382810) https://superuser.com/a/1382810